# How to pass POINT structure to ElementFromPoint method in Python?

Tags: python, com, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation, comtypes

I'm trying to use method **[IUIAutomation::ElementFromPoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee671538.aspx)** in Python using **[comtypes](https://github.com/enthought/comtypes)** package. There are many examples how to use it in C++, but not in Python. This simple code reproduces the problem on 64-bit Windows 10 (Python 2.7 32-bit):

```
import comtypes.client

UIA_dll = comtypes.client.GetModule('UIAutomationCore.dll')
UIA_dll.IUIAutomation().ElementFromPoint(10, 10)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Expected a COM this pointer as first argument
```

Creating the `POINT` structure this way doesn't help as well:

```
from ctypes import Structure, c_long

class POINT(Structure):
    _pack_ = 4
    _fields_ = [
        ('x', c_long),
        ('y', c_long),
    ]

point = POINT(10, 10)
UIA_dll.IUIAutomation().ElementFromPoint(point) # raises the same exception
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reuse existing POINT structure definition directly, like this:

```
import comtypes
from comtypes import *
from comtypes.client import *

comtypes.client.GetModule('UIAutomationCore.dll')
from comtypes.gen.UIAutomationClient import *

# get IUIAutomation interface
uia = CreateObject(CUIAutomation._reg_clsid_, interface=IUIAutomation)

# import tagPOINT from wintypes
from ctypes.wintypes import tagPOINT
point = tagPOINT(10, 10)
element = uia.ElementFromPoint(point)

rc = element.currentBoundingRectangle # of type ctypes.wintypes.RECT
print("Element bounds left:", rc.left, "right:", rc.right, "top:", rc.top, "bottom:", rc.bottom)
```

To determine what's the expected type for `ElementFromPoint`, you can just go to your python setup directory (for me it was `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\comtypes\gen`) and check the files in there. It should contains files automatically generated by comtypes, including the one for UIAutomationCore.dll. The interesting file name starts with _944DE083_8FB8_45CF_BCB7_C477ACB2F897 (the COM type lib's GUID).

The file contains this:

```
COMMETHOD([], HRESULT, 'ElementFromPoint',
          ( ['in'], tagPOINT, 'pt' ),
```

This tells you that it expects a `tagPOINT` type. And this type is defined a the beginning of the file like this:

```
from ctypes.wintypes import tagPOINT
```

It's named tagPOINT because that's how it's defined in original [Windows header](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162805.aspx).

Comment: Thank you, Simon! This is exactly what I need.